# Geoform for points, lines and polygons in QGIS environment

Tags: software-recommendations, web-gis, crowdsourcing

I've been asked to look for an attractive way to collect information from children and young adults about the routes they are using to go to school, sports club, etc., as well as the points on the road which they consider as dangerous.

This should be a combination between a questionnaire and a webmap on which the participants of the online survey can indicate lines (routes) and points (dangerous points).

Ideally the data of the online survey can be used afterwards in, for example, a QGIS environment for further analysis.

I know about the "Geoform", accessible through the WebApp Builder of ArcGIS Online, for which I know you certainly can collect points, but I'm looking for a free-of-charge solution for which no commercial licenses are needed.

Any suggestions about the needed configuration?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a form creating with [jotform](https://www.jotform.com).
Using this [widget](http://widgets.jotform.com/widget/geolocation)
It's free for limited use. 
You can storage the data in a google spreadsheet and create simple google map visualization or export to use with qgis.

Comment: I have tried your suggestion of Jotform, but, as you mentioned, it is no longer free of charge when you expect a high amount of submissions. In addition to that, the widget only allows to select 1 single point. You could add the same widget several times, but the ideal solution would allow to select several locations in 1 single map and define some information for each location (e.g. why do you consider the location of this point as a "dangerous" point?)

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few options that might serve this use-case. Most of them allow data export to a format you can bring into QGIS.

[canvis.app](https://about.canvis.app) - quick and free to get up and running for basic point geoforms.

[maptionnaire](https://maptionnaire.com) - geared towards researchers and planners, can be quite pricey but is a great user-friendly tool.

Google MyMaps, not intended for large-scale surveys, but works for small supervised projects.

Various ArcGIS Online tools, like Crowdsource Reporter and WebApp Builder. Of course these are enterprise grade tools, might be cumbersome and expensive for you.

Other tools I am less familiar with:
Spotteron, [EmotionalMaps](https://www.pocitovemapy.cz/index-en.html)